# Invisible runtime errors in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, embedded-linux, runtime-error

I am writing a `C++` application for an embedded Linux. I have a problem where runtime errors, like unhandled exceptions and segmentation faults, that occur in threads other than the main thread are not displayed in the console. In such cases my application will be terminated abruptly without any error message. Is there any way to get the error messages to the default console of the parent main thread? (`gdb` is not supported on my embedded linux)

Comment: Write them to a log? - you could mutex a big character buffer, have the threads write to that, dump it in a log.

Comment: I could imagine to write a thread wrapper which catches `unhandled exceptions` and write these to a log file, but how should real `runtime-errors` like `segmentation faults` be catched/dumped to a log file?

Comment: @Dudero: Linux uses a mechanism called signal handling through which you can catch various hardware errors.

Comment: @DeadMG: thanks, that sounds very interesting, I will google for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that these `runtime-errors` are displayed in the `syslog` files, that completely fulfills my requirements.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't let exceptions propagate out of your thread function.  Typically you would have a catch all exception handler around the body of your thread function.  How you handle these exceptions is then down to you.

Comment: thank you, for exceptions I agree with you, there should be always a `catch(...)`-block to prevent leaving the thread function.